# Why when i want to rename column i have Debug R error?

Tags: r

I run this code

`for (i in 1:21) { colnames(SRR[[i]])[9] <- srr_list[[i]] }`

SRR list has data frames [[1]], [[2]]... and columns into it.

srrlist is list too, but inside 1-21

```
 [1] "./SRR10085693.abu.tab" "./SRR10085694.abu.tab" "./SRR10566482.abu.tab" "./SRR11089998.abu.tab..."
```

But have this error

```
debug на #2: colnames(SRR[[i]])[9] <- srr_list[[i]]
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What does `class(SRR)` give ?

Comment: How `colnames`, `SRR` and `srr_list` are defined? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BastienDucreux its "[1] "list"" of data frames